# search for hexadecimal number on python using re

Tags: python, regex

I am processing an html text file, and serching for hexadecimal numbers as follows:

```
example    \xb7\xc7\xa0....
```

I tried with this code

```
t=re.findall (r'\\x[0-9a-fA-F]+', line)
```

but I can only gained empty list.

please tell the right way of writing the code.

Comment: Marcelo, your edit completely breaks the point of this question! The original version only had a single backslash escape, which is why the code didn't work. Mark Byers' answer was correct.

Comment: @JukkaZitting: Check the *source* for the original version. It had two backslashes, which was rendered as one because it wasn't formatted as code.

Comment: @pyfunc: by editing the question, you made it wrong to write, in which case there should not be a problem now :-)

Comment: @JukkaZitting: Hmm, it's possible that the OP typed a double-backslash twice with the intent of having it present as  single backslash. But, given that the OP is posting for the first time, it seems more likely that they pasted the code as-is, not realising it would un-double their backslash. Frankly, it surprises *me* that it un-doubled it; are backslashes special outside code?

Comment: @GregHewgill: I see, you're right. user1078785: Did the code you originally used have the double escape?

Comment: no, single escape only in the text.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine if the backslash is escaped inside the regular expression:

```
t = re.findall (r'\\x[0-9a-fA-F]+', line)
```

Result:

```
['\\xb7', '\\xc7', '\\xa0']
```

ideone: http://ideone.com/MPO5j

---

If it doesn't work it might be because you string contains literal binary characters. Then try something like this instead:

```
t = re.findall (r'[\x80-\xff]', line)
```

ideone: http://ideone.com/ChIsh

Comment: Unless there was an edit I didn't catch, the OP did escape it.

Comment: Marcelo, you yourself edited the post to add the required escape!

Comment: thanks! your approach  is so expressed for me. thank you again.

Comment: @JukkaZitting: Yes, you're right. I didn't realise the effect of my edit until after I commented on this answer.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me. Two scenarios come to mind that might explain your problem:

1. You're testing this by assigning the string to a variable `line` like so:

   ```
   line = 'example    \xb7\xc7\xa0....'
   ```

   In this case, you need to escape the backslashes:

   ```
   line = 'example    \\xb7\\xc7\\xa0....'
   ```
2. You are viewing the contents of the file or line as a Python string, so that the `\xb7` you are seeing is actually the character who's code is B7 hex, not the character sequence `'\', '\x', 'b', '7'`.

Comment: if i write as follows:    t=re.findall (r'\x[0-9a-fA-F]+', line)      this kind of message retuned: sre_constants.error: bogus escape: '\\x'. This confused me very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me:

```
>>> line = r'\xb7\xc7\xa0....'
>>> t=re.findall (r'\\x[0-9a-fA-F]+', line)
>>> t
['\\xb7', '\\xc7', '\\xa0']
```

Comment: thank you. The example would be not good for telling my trouble!