# Search Hexadecimal List in a binary file using Python

Tags: python, regex, search, hex, binaryfiles

I need to find the Hexadecimal Pattern in a Binary file

My Pattern is as follows:

```
s1_pattern =  ['\x47\x02','\x47\x12','\x47\x22','\x47\x32','\x47\x42','\x47\x52','\x47\x62''\x47\x72''\x47\x82','\x47\x92']
```

If you see above, in the \x(0)2 the first bit shown in brackets can be any value from 0-9, I just need to find the pattern in a file and count the list of occurances. Currently I am getting an answer for searching individual
values using the following link [search for hexadecimal number on python using re](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366682/search-for-hexadecimal-number-on-python-using-re).

How to count for all occurrences in the list in a binary file? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: Need the count of all occurrences in the list.

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. What have you tried, how is it not working? What can't you figure out? Please add more details to your question.

Comment: I am aware that this isn't code writing service. I am just asking help out here to someone who has done this before or could guide me on this.

Comment: Again, you *need to provide more details*. A good place to start is an example input and expected output.